# How to convert rgb mask to categorical in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I try to find a proper solution to convert a rgb mask from "cam vid" dataset to categorical mask.

I have the list of rgb value and corresponding label. What is the proper way to generate a categorical label in keras?

A "cam vids" dataset looks like this:

```
.
├── default
│   └── 000048-NG.jpg
├── defaultannot
│   └── 000048-NG.png
├── default.txt
└── label_colors.txt

2 directories, 4 files
```

Comment: use `tf.one_hot`.

Answer (score 0):

I read your question and separate your question into two requirements

1. From the recording camera, you need to convert the output to the dataset with category and
2. Generate the categorizing label

That depends on your model learning and assumption of the input and target when you can use supervised learning, self-supervised learning, or unsupervised learning.

**[ Sample ]:** Quick sample of supervised learning return label .

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

import tensorflow as tf

import os
from os.path import exists

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
fig = plt.figure()
image = plt.imread( "F:\\datasets\\downloads\\cats_name\\train\\Symbols\\01.jpg" )
im = plt.imshow( image )

list_actual_label = [ 'Shoes', 'Duck' ]

global video_capture_0
video_capture_0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
loggings = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\loggings.log"

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Functions
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
def f1( picture ):
    return tf.constant( picture ).numpy()

def animate( i ):
    ret0, frame0 = video_capture_0.read()
    if (ret0):      
        
        frame0 = tf.image.resize(frame0, [29, 39]).numpy()
        
        temp = img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(frame0[:,:,2:3])
        temp2 = img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(frame0[:,:,1:2])
        temp3 = img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(frame0[:,:,0:1])

        temp = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=2)([temp, temp2])
        temp = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=2)([temp, temp3])
        # 480, 640
        temp = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(
            temp,
            data_format=None,
            scale=True
        )
        temp = f1( temp )
        
        im.set_array( temp )
        result = predict_action( temp )
        print( list_actual_label[result] )
        
    return im,

def predict_action ( image ) :
    predictions = model.predict(tf.constant(image, shape=(1, 29, 39, 3) , dtype=tf.float32))
    result = tf.math.argmax(predictions[0])
    return result

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 29, 39, 3 )),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((234, 32)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32)),
])
        
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2))
model.summary()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
list_picture = []
list_label = []
path_1 = "F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Duck_Shoe\\Duck\\"
path_2 = "F:\\datasets\\downloads\\Duck_Shoe\\Shoes\\"

for file in os.listdir( path_1 ):
    image = plt.imread( path_1 + file )
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [29, 39]).numpy()

    for i in range ( 40 ) :
        if i % 6 == 0 :
            layer = tf.keras.layers.RandomZoom(.5, .2)
            image = layer( image ).numpy()
            list_picture.append( image )
        elif i % 5 == 0 :
            image = tf.image.random_hue(image, 0.2).numpy()
            image = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(image, 1).numpy()
            list_picture.append( image )
        elif i % 4 == 0 :
            image = tf.image.random_saturation(image, 5, 10, 1).numpy()
            image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image, 1).numpy()
            list_picture.append( image )
        elif i % 3 == 0 :
            image = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(image, 1).numpy()
            image = tf.image.random_saturation(image, 5, 10, 1).numpy()
            list_picture.append( image )
        elif i % 2 == 0 :
            image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image, 1).numpy()
            image = tf.image.random_hue(image, 0.2).numpy()
            list_picture.append( image )
        else :
            list_picture.append( image )
        
        list_label.append( 1 )

for file in os.listdir( path_2 ):
    image = plt.imread( path_2 + file )
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [29, 39]).numpy()
    
    for i in range ( 40 ) :
        if i % 6 == 0 :
            layer = tf.keras.layers.RandomZoom(.5, .2)
            image = layer( image ).numpy()
            list_picture.append( image )
        elif i % 5 == 0 :
            image = tf.image.random_hue(image, 0.2).numpy()
            image = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(image, 1).numpy()
            list_picture.append( image )
        elif i % 4 == 0 :
            image = tf.image.random_saturation(image, 5, 10, 1).numpy()
            image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image, 1).numpy()
            list_picture.append( image )
        elif i % 3 == 0 :
            image = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(image, 1).numpy()
            image = tf.image.random_saturation(image, 5, 10, 1).numpy()
            list_picture.append( image )
        elif i % 2 == 0 :
            image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image, 1).numpy()
            image = tf.image.random_hue(image, 0.2).numpy()
            list_picture.append( image )
        else :
            list_picture.append( image )
            
        list_label.append( 0 )

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant([list_picture], shape=(len(list_picture), 1, 29, 39, 3), dtype=tf.float32),tf.constant([list_label], shape=(len(list_picture), 1, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam( learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07, name='Nadam' )

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredLogarithmicError(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO, name='mean_squared_logarithmic_error')

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=['accuracy'])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: FileWriter
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
if exists(checkpoint_path) :
    model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
    print("model load: " + checkpoint_path)
    input("Press Any Key!")

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=2 ,validation_data=(dataset))
model.save_weights(checkpoint_path)

while True:
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=50, blit=True)
    plt.show()


# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture_0.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()



input('...')
```